# sqoop import from DB2 to Datastax, schema not in proper format - 1

Tags: db2, hive, sqoop, cql3, datastax-enterprise

Please see the below extracts and advice how to do a Hive query like (Select PREDNO, STAGE from actest2;) as the data imported using sqoop command of Datastax 3.2.0 is not in proper format?

Representation of data on DB2 Database, when select * from SchemaName.TableName order by PREDNO with ur;

ORDERNO    PREDNO    STAGE
-------------------------------------------------
16,448             2               SCREENING
16,448             3               MATCHING
16,448             4               MATCHING
16,448             5               STAGE1

Representation of data on Datastax 3.2.0, using hive prompt post import of data using sqoop command.
Please note DB2 column names are appearing under column1 of HIVE.

Logging initialized using configuration in file:/u/dse-3.2.0/resources/hive/conf/hive-log4j.properties
Hive history file=/tmp/padmn/hive_job_log_padmn_201312100943_1762004529.txt
hive (default)>

hive (SqoopTest)> select * from actest2;
OK
key         column1       value
----    ---------   ------
4          ORDERNO        16448
4          STAGE               MATCHING
15        ORDERNO      16448
15        STAGE              MATCHING
11        ORDERNO      16448
11        STAGE              STAGE1

Representation of data on Datastax 3.2.0, using CQL 3.0 prompt post import of data using sqoop command.
Please note DB2 column names are appearing under column1 of CQLSH 3.0.

[cqlsh 3.1.7 | Cassandra 1.2.11.2 | CQL spec 3.0.0 | Thrift protocol 19.36.1]
Use HELP for help.
cqlsh> use "SqoopTest";
cqlsh:SqoopTest> select * from actest2;

key | column1      | value
-----+--------------+-----------------------
   3 |      ORDERNO |                 16448
   3 |        STAGE |             MATCHING
   6 |      ORDERNO |                 16448
   6 |        STAGE |             STAGE2
   5 |      ORDERNO |                 16448
   5 |        STAGE |             STAGE1

Comment: Looks like you might have got the mapping wrong here, when you used sqoop to import the data, how did you lay out your mapping? This link provides a good reference to the sqoop options. http://docs.datastax.com/en/datastax_enterprise/4.5/datastax_enterprise/ana/anaSqpRef.html. I'm interested in what you had for `--cassandra-column-mapping`